# Formatting: String cannot be converted to String[]

Tags: java, arrays, formatting, joptionpane

> Using the data array, create instances of books and store them in a one-dimensional array of `Book`, called `bookArray`. Using the quantity array, walk through the book array and calculate the total charge per book sold. Print in a dialog box the book title, the book isbn, and the total charge for each book. Then, print the grand total of all books sold.

So far I have done this, but I'm having issue with the `JOptionPane` and formatting.

Error

```
$ javac BookTest.java
BookTest.java:41: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to String[][]
        dataArray +=String.format(" %s, %s ", b.getTitle(), b.getIsbn());
                                 ^
1 error
```

And the code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class BookTest { 
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String dataArray  [][]=
         {{ "Fiction", "Abraham Lincoln Vampire Hunter", "Grahame-Smith", "Wiley", "NY", "978-0446563079", "13.99", "222"},
          {"Fiction", "Frankenstein", "Shelley", "Prescott", "GA", "978-0486282114", "7.99", "321"},
          {"NonFiction", "Life of Kennedy", "Jones", "Pearson", "MT", "758-29304566", "12.90", "biography"},
          {"Fiction", "Dracula", "Stoker", "Addison", "CA", "978-0486411095","5.99", "145"},
          {"Fiction", "Curse of the Wolfman", "Hageman", "Wesley", "MA", "B00381AKHG", "10.59", "876"},
          {"NonFiction", "How to Pass Java", "Willis", "Wiley"," NY", "444-395869790", "1.99", "technology"},
          {"Fiction", "The Mummy", "Rice", "Addision", "CA", "978-0345369949", "7.99", "954"},
          {"NonFiction", "History of Texas", "Smith", "Prescott", "CA", "123-683947687", "9.75", "history"}
         };

      Book bookArray[] = new Book [8];

      for (int i = 0; i < bookArray.length; i++) {
         if (dataArray[i][0].equals("Fiction")) {
            Publisher p = new Publisher(dataArray[i][3], dataArray[i][4]);
            bookArray[i] = new Fiction(dataArray[i][1], dataArray[i][2], dataArray[i][5],
               p, Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i][6]), dataArray[i][7]);
         } else {
            Publisher p = new Publisher(dataArray[i][3], dataArray[i][4]);
            bookArray[i] = new NonFiction(dataArray[i][1], dataArray[i][2], dataArray[i][5],
               p, Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i][6]), dataArray[i][7]);
         }
      }

      for (Book b:bookArray) {
        dataArray +=String.format(" %s, %s ", b.getTitle(), b.getIsbn());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, dataArray);     
      }
   }        
}
```

Comment: what issue are you phasing ? can you attached image if possible then

Comment: @vishalgajera Below is the error I'm getting and also I'm trying to figure out how to get this done. 

Write BookTest to create all books and calculate the charge.  The quantity will be in a one-dimensional array as follows.

12 8 3 53 7 23 14 5

Error:
prashanas-MBP:JAVA PrashanaTimilsina$ javac BookTest.java
BookTest.java:41: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to String[][]
   dataArray +=String.format(" %s, %s ", b.getTitle(), b.getIsbn());
                            ^
1 error
prashanas-MBP:JAVA PrashanaTimilsina$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use your `dataArray` to output things in the message box. **Use a** `String` **variable**.

```
for (Book b : bookArray) {
    String bookOutput = String.format(" %s, %s ", b.getTitle(), b.getIsbn());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bookOutput);
}
```

**Even better**, add a `toString()` to your `Book` class that returns `String.format(" %s, %s ", getTitle(), getIsbn())` and then do your loop like *this*:

```
for (Book b : bookArray) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, b.toString());
}
```

**However**, if you want to output the price for each book and then the total, your loop will look more like *this*:

```
double totalPrice = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < bookArray.length; i++) { //can't use foreach because of use of parallel arrays bookArray & quantityArray
    Book b = bookArray[i];
    double price = b.getPrice() * quantityArray[i];
    totalPrice += price;
    String bookStr = String.format(" %s, %s %s", b.getTitle(), b.getIsbn(), 
        DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(price));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bookStr);
}
String totalStr = String.format("Total Charge: %s", 
    DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(totalPrice)));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, totalStr);
```

Comment: @4casle, thanks for the help, i got couple of questions can you please guide me.   

    BookTest.java:44: error: bad operand types for binary operator '*'
    double price = b.getPrice() * dataArray[i];
                                ^
    first type:  double
    second type: String[]
    BookTest.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
  
for the getCurrencyInstance is this calling this class

public double calculatecharge(int qtySold)
 {
  double totalCharge; 
  totalCharge = qtySold * getPrice();
  return totalCharge; 
 }

Comment: Yes, if you have a method already in your `Book` class which can calculate the charge then use that instead. Replace the 4th line of my last chunk of code with `double price = b.calculatecharge(quantityArray[i]);`. Also, you got that "bad operand" error because you used the wrong array in your price calculation. Use the `quantityArray` instead of the `dataArray`.

Answer (score 1):

[`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) returns a `String` as per the docs. You are trying to concatenate a `String` to a 2d array.

```
dataArray +=String.format(" %s, %s ", b.getTitle(), b.getIsbn());
```

In the above line you probably want to access a location from the 2d array, like `dataArray[0][0]` and then do the concatenation. Something like:

```
dataArray[0][0] +=String.format(" %s, %s ", b.getTitle(), b.getIsbn());
```

Comment: I don't think you read the goal of his program, he isn't looking to change any values in `dataArray`, he just wants to display the books as a String.